# CMD Batch rename. Read new names from text file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have a directory of product images that I'd like to rename to the products's UPC. I have the file name mapping in a spreadsheet, so I can export it to CSV or tab delimited.

Given filenames.txt:

```
CurrentName     NewName
DSCN4033.png    750732000259.png
DSCN4023.png    750732000013.png
DSCN4024.png    750732000020.png
DSCN4022.png    750732000099.png
```

DSCN4033.png would become 750732000259.png

If I were doing this with Bash, the command would be

> while read old new; do mv "$old" "$new"; done < filenames.txt

This is for a project at work that must be done with a Windows batch file so that my successors don't have to mess with Cygwin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided there are no spaces in your current names, then the following should work from the command line:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1*" %A in (filenames.txt) do ren "%A" "%B"
```

The percents must be doubled if put in a batch file:

```
@for /f "skip=1 tokens=1*" %%A in (filenames.txt) do ren "%%A" "%%B"
```

FOR is the most complicated internal command available to CMD.EXE. Use `help for` or `for /?` from the command line to access the documentation.

Comment: Whoa. I never would have thought to look inside FOR for this kind of functionality.